# How to use enum values to index an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an object that uses `enum` values as keys. I'd like to iterate those `enum` values and use them to index the said object:

```
enum Foods {
  bread = "bread",
  meat = "meat",
}

type ShoppingList = {
  [Foods.bread]: string;
  [Foods.meat]: string;
};

const shoppingList: ShoppingList = {
  bread: "1 loaf",
  meat: "2 lbs",
};

Object.keys(Foods).forEach((item) => {
  console.log(shoppingList[item]);
});
```

This *does* build with `tsc`, but `ts-node` and VS Code are both reporting:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
  'string'  can't be used to index type 'ShoppingList'. No index signature with
  a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ShoppingList'.

17   console.log(shoppingList[item]);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Understandable, because `Object.keys` returns `string[]`. However, you and I know that those strings will *only* ever be members of `Foods`. And because `ShoppingList` *only* uses `Foods` as its keys, we should be able to use any member of `Object.keys` to index `shoppingList`.

This makes sense conceptually but how would I communicate this to TypeScript?

**Edit**: `Foods` and `ShoppingList` need to stick to those two values, i.e. no dynamic keys here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't using only an `enum`.

You could of course just use casting to tell TS what the type of `item` will be:

```
console.log(shoppingList[item as Foods]);
```

But that would get tiresome to write every time you need to cast `Foods`.

Another option would be to declare an array that is explicitly defined:

```
enum Foods {
  bread = "bread",
  meat = "meat",
}

const FoodsArray = [Foods.bread, Foods.meat];

// Optional: use [key in Foods] to consolidate type definition
type ShoppingList = {
  [key in Foods]: string;
};

const shoppingList: ShoppingList = {
  bread: "1 loaf",
  meat: "2 lbs",
};

FoodsArray.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(shoppingList[item]);
});
```

Is it a bit redundant to have to manually declare and update an array? Yes. But as far as I know there is no way to infer accurate types directly from an `enum`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=17&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nAJgZygbwFBSgIwE7ACGiUAvFAET5GIUA0WUERALmZc4S-RgL4YYAxnBDI28JMgCCePIQCe7ANoSUAOmrE6sBOs4sAugG4BLeQAdgUAMoALOOfMBLEAHMAMk7HtM2JQGtgRRcdSQMALigxPBdXE14TIRFvZHtHWM8xSLsHZzdMtnJfXAJiSIoARigAGzhCADMebH1ygCYanGQeBIFVaVkFNXq4PABRQkFbAAoppxZgCABKMgA+dEZhUThq4DVa1ynU3IyvFiU5hYNF+OugA